# simple repeated call of array in typescript of react doesnt work in 1 case of similar 3 cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi there i'm coding simple todo apps with react.js/typescript.
i'm stuck with calling repeatedly todos

i could call todo at 1) and 3) but I **COUDNT call 2)** .

whats the difference. maybe my interface type makes bad in `todo.type.tsx` ?

1. `<TodoListItem todo={todos[0]} />`
2. `{todos.map(todo=> { <TodoListItem todo={todo} />  })}`
3. `{todos.map(todo => (<li>{todo.text} - {todo.email2}</li> ))}`

or my Props2  calling in `todo.tsx` is bad ?

`React.FC<Props2> = ({ todo })`

this is shown

```
==== ( localhost:9000 rendering shows this ) ======
text1"[shown in TodoListItem]"contato@gabrielrufino.com
text1 - contato@gabrielrufino.com
text2 - darthvader@starwars.com
```

src/pages/index.tsx

```js
    import { TodoListItem } from '../components/todo';

    export default function IndexPage(){
    
      const [todos, setTods] = useState<Todo[]>([
          {
            text: 'todo1',
            email2: 'contato@gabrielrufino.com'
          },
          {
            text: "todo2",
            email2: 'darthvader@starwars.com'
          }
        ])
    
      return (
          <Layout>
            <TodoListItem todo={todos[0]} />   // ★I can call   (★1)
            <ul>
              {todos.map(todo=> {
                 <TodoListItem todo={todo} />  //  ★I CANT call (★2)
              })}
            </ul>
            <ul>
            {todos.map(todo => (
              <li>{todo.text} - {todo.email2}</li> // ★I can call   (★3)
            ))}
           </ul>
          </Layout>
        )
    }
```

src/model/todo.type.tsx

```js
    interface Todo {
        text: string;
        email2: string;
      }

      interface Props2 {
        todo: Todo;
      }
```

src/components/todo.tsx

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';


export const TodoListItem: React.FC<Props2> = ({ todo }) => {
    return (
      <li>
         {todo.text} 
           <br> "shown in TodoListItem"
           </br>
         {todo.email2}
      </li>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that it was not returning at all.

Try

```
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo: Todo) => (
          <TodoListItem todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
```

or

```
       <ul>
          {todos.map(todo=> {
             return <TodoListItem todo={todo} /> 
           })}
       </ul>
```

instead of

```
        <ul>
          {todos.map(todo=> {
             <TodoListItem todo={todo} />  //  ★I CANT call (★2)
           })}
        </ul>
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bartik-vl8hs

Comment: @oshigoto46, check this out!!

Comment: thanks for it including code-sandbox !!!

its very attractive!

Answer (score 0):

You have made a **bracketing error**. For any function in JS/TS the `()` signify returning (you don't even have to use the keyword `return`) whereas `{}` signifies simply running the function

In your `index.tsx` file :

```
    import { TodoListItem } from '../components/todo';

    export default function IndexPage(){
    
      const [todos, setTods] = useState<Todo[]>([
          {
            text: 'todo1',
            email2: 'contato@gabrielrufino.com'
          },
          {
            text: "todo2",
            email2: 'darthvader@starwars.com'
          }
        ])
    
      return (
          <Layout>
            <TodoListItem todo={todos[0]} />   // ★I can call   (★1)
            
            //Here, inside the map function you have used "{}" instead of "()" so the map function is simply iterating and not returning anything.
           

            <ul>
              {todos.map(todo=> {
                 <TodoListItem todo={todo} />  //  ★I CANT call (★2)
              })}
            </ul>





            <ul>
            {todos.map(todo => (
              <li>{todo.text} - {todo.email2}</li> // ★I can call   (★3)
            ))}
           </ul>
          </Layout>
        )
    }
```

The fixes for this could be

```
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo: Todo) => (
          <TodoListItem todo={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
```

or

```
        <ul>
          {todos.map(todo=> {
             return <TodoListItem todo={todo} /> 
           })}
       </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for it . to be honest i randomly chooose `{` or `(` ..

curly brackets and return makes some `closure` thats enables returning for multiple times ??

 {todos.map(todo=> { 
             return <TodoListItem todo={todo} />  
           })}
<br/>

Comment: No worries mate. Can you please provide an upvote to this solution to guide future students to this working answer ?